# UISlider Custom Thumb Image Resizing Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5, xcode4.5

I want to get directions for following two issues related to UISlider control customization.

**Issues#1:**
I just updated the UISlideThumbImage as seen in following screenshot. As thumb image is in retina display, so its large image; My question is how we can resize the thumb image? I don't want to resize thumb image PNG. If i will do that then on retina display screens, it will seems blur.
[image]

**Issue#2:**
Default clickable area of thumb image of slider is 23x23. How we can increase that area? So that we can adjust it according to the size of thumb image. Currently, if i will move finger in 23x23 bounds, it will start sliding but if out side of that bound, it will not move but i also want to move the thumb if i will slide on any place of the thumb image.

Your important suggestions will be move helpful in this regards. Is there any third party library present which will do it more efficiently regardless of doing it ourself and spend more time over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience with customising UISlider, It's better just not using the default one.
There is a open source Range Slider:

https://github.com/muZZkat/NMRangeSlider

And notice there is a option to remove the lower thumb so you acutely have a regular customising UISlider

"(New) Disable lower handle so it behaves like a regular UISlider but still use other features."

Comment: You are right; Its better to use any library instead of customization of default one.